# mouseMoved to ignore QCursor.setPos()?

Tags: qt, cursor, mouseevent

I'm calling QCursor.setPos() while the cursor is inside my widget.  When I do, mouseMoveEvent is called, when I don't want it to be.  In Java/Swing I can move the cursor without sending events.  Can I do something similar so calls to QCursor.setPos() so don't send a mouseMoveEvent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just keeping track of the difference in between mouse movements, so if I get a mouse movement of 5 to the right, for example, I store the five and ignore the next event if it moves me 5 to the left (which means it's probably called by setPos).  Not really elegant, but it appears to work reliably.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
myWidget->clearFocus();
QCursor::setPos(pos);
myWidget->setFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to setPos without trigger mouseMoveEvent,
maybe you consider create a :

```
bool disableMoveProcess;
```

and make it as a flag for provent your logic running?

I use this method for calling QListWidgetItem::setSelected 
without make QListWidget::itemSelectionChanged trigger my code.